# jBPM: running on JRE and not on JDK

Tags: jbpm

I am working with jBPM and to learn how to use a webservice component, I followed this example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5rvLNmeRB4

Deployment works without any errors.

But at the creation of a new process instance and entering the values of the variables into the form (video at 17:10), I get the following error message:

"Unable to complete your request. The following exception occured:"Unable to create response: [webservice-integration.WebService:228 - Webservice:2] -- java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compiler detected, make sure you're running on top of a JDK instead of a JRE."

Where can I set this?

Comment: Are you working on Windows or Linux? Could you check if you have JDK installed and $JAVA_HOME points to JDK, not to JRE? (check with %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac -version in Windows, or java -version in Linux)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.